# Could a horse-sized wolf-like animal out run a horse?

Tags: creature-design

I an making a medieval society that uses a wolf-like animal as steeds instead of horses (in case it helps to have a description, think of a wolf built like a deer) and I wanted to know if it could out-run a horse within a hundred meters of each other.

Comment: It can if you want it to.  Really.

Comment: a wolf with hooves?

Comment: over what distance? Humans (fit ones) can outrun a horse over a long enough distance. We hunted horses and other animals like antelope like this (still do in some places), just ran them into the ground and then speared them when they stop from heat exhaustion.

Comment: How did your riders deal with the fact wolves don't run with a straight spine as horses do?

Comment: @AlbertoYagos: One would assume that you only ride the animal if you're capable of riding it. Warg/wolf riders are not a new thing - both LOTR and Warcraft spring to mind here.

Comment: A wolf built like a deer would be a rather poor predator.

Comment: *"in case it helps to have a description, think of a wolf built like a deer"* so, basically, it is a deer.

Answer (score 4):

Realistically? No. Horses have skinny limbs for a reason... so there's less weight to move as their legs go back and forth, and really hefty muscles at the base of each. A horse will outrun the wolf, but their weaker limbs (limbs themselves, not the base) will make it hard to struggle if wolves surround them (as wolves generally try to do.)

Unless, of course, the horse is weak for some reason. (Already exerted, tired, old, young, etc.)

Comment: As a purely practical test, my dog (about 70 lbs, probably a Plott Hound or mix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plott_Hound ) can keep up with my horse at a canter or moderate gallop.  Admittedly, the horse is a mustang with probably a good bit of draft in his ancestry, not a racehorse :-)  And of course sled dogs have just about everything beat for endurance.  So something bred from ancestral wolves might make a fast steed.

Comment: Dogs are also much smaller they have less mass to move. So I don't doubt your dog could outrun a horse, same with a sled dog. Scaling them up would actually reduce their speed. Its the same situation with why you can't have giant ants. Sure at their size they can carry 10x their weight, but at large size, they wouldn't be able to carry their own weight.

Comment: This answer confuses me. Wolves already run faster than a horses, on average. Are you suggesting that a larger wolf would run slower? I think arguments could be made on both sides potentially, however, since it's the OP's story, this is now solely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Scaling an animal does not scale its performance, as defined by [the square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law): _"If an animal were isometrically scaled up by a considerable amount, its relative muscular strength would be severely reduced, since the cross section of its muscles would increase by the square of the scaling factor while its mass would increase by the cube of the scaling factor."_ Additionally, when you scale an animal up, its mass (= volume = m³) scales up faster than e.g. oxygen intake (= lung surface area = m²) for the same reason.

Comment: While I do agree with the answer, _"Horses have skinny limbs for a reason."_ is not a valid reason to suggest that muscular animals wouldn't be able to run fast. Just because one animal species has solved a particular problem one way does not mean that other solutions are not available. For example: birds have evolved feathers for flight, but bats use a wing made of skin. Two different solutions to the same problem. The existence of one does not disprove the other.

Comment: @Flater I fully understand the square-cube law, as it is frequently tossed out on this site. My point is that nobody can definitively tell whether a wolf 'as large as a horse' could still outrun a horse. Isometric scaling is but one method of increasing size, which is ironic because you basically say the exact same thing in your second response without even probably realizing it. To put it a bit more simply: A house cat "scaled" to a cheetah's size couldn't outrun a cheetah, and yet the cheetah is larger. Your generic "square-cube" law comment wouldn't apply. The same for "wolf-like" vs. wolf.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Following google (upper range): Horses top speed 48kph, wolves top speed 60kph. Horses height 1.8m, Wolves 0.9m; so a scaling factor of 2. For a wolf twice the size, you're looking at 4x the muscle strength (2²) but 8x the mass (2³), so you're looking at a 50% efficiency loss, which I'm spitballing as half of the top speed = 30kph, which is not as fast as a horse. There are of course many more detailed things to consider but the back-of-the-napkin calculation puts **horse-sized wolves at around 62.5% of a horse's speed**, just over half of what you need to outrun a horse.

Comment: @ColonelPanic `The same for "wolf-like" vs. wolf.` If you're playing that card then the question is effectively unanswerable without knowing the precise biological makeup of this wolf-like animal. The assumption is that they are physical equivalents, regardless of their genetic ancestry and whether or not they are related to wolves.

Comment: Seconding Flater's comment. Pointing out your own answer @ColonelPanic, If you're changing proportions significantly, it will cease to b wolf-like the same way a cheetah isn't a housecat-like. Now a creature roughly BASED on a wolf might be able to outrun a horse, but it'd look much different; cutting weight in various areas for example and centralizing mass. (Much like the cheetah and the horse do.)

Comment: You only think horse limbs are weak because you've never been kicked by one.

Comment: @Renan You only think the limbs aren't weak because you've been kicked by them. The limbs themselves ARE weak. The strength of the kick actually comes from their rump muscles and that it's almost pure bone in a column after that force. It's like stabbing a spear at someone. Getting kicked by a horse (which relies on rump muscles) is horrible. Getting kneed by a horse, however (which relies on their mid-leg muscles) is pretty much unheard of.

Comment: @liljoshu I never took a kick myself, but I almost graduated as a veterinarian. I did see a couple surgeries done on horses at college. And I grew up in a farm. I think they are pretty strong, especially to move a half a ton bugger all day long.

Comment: @Renan They are impressive, I'll give you that. But most of their strength comes from their rump & torso, almost none of it from their limbs themselves.

Comment: @liljoshu: Your logic is faulty.  If size were all that mattered, mice could outrun horses, and larger animals such as the hippopotamus & rhinocerous.  And the reason you can't have a horse-sized ant is that neither the exoskeleton nor the respiratory system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_system_of_insects will scale up.  You could certainly have an animal with endoskeleton & vertebrate-like respiratory system that looked rather like an ant.

Comment: @liljoshu: Re horse legs, ever looked at a dog's legs?  Same basic design, thin legs getting most of their power from rump & shoulder muscles.

Comment: @jamesqf They look thin, but if you look at the legs width vs their body's thickness, you'll find they're actually quite thick. Scaled up to a horse's size, a golden retriever's leg would be more than eight inches across at the ankle, which is closer to a horse's hoof, not ankle, which would more than double the mass of the leg as a whole over that of a horse.

Comment: @liljoshu: Neither the OP nor I are talking about simply "scaling up" an animal.  As the wolf-based animal evolved to a larger size, the relative dimensions of limbs &c would change accordingly.  See for instance the difference in various large breeds of dogs, e.g Saint Bernards vs Great Dane (especially if you disregard the hair), or the legs of draft horses vs thorobreds.  Or why the hippopotamus can run quite fast on land, despite its short, thick legs.

Comment: @jamesqf but at that point, can you really consider it wolf-like, or is it simply wolf-derived? You wouldn't call humans mouse-like despite the fact we evolved from what was a mousey creature back in the cretaceous era. As for the hippo, it mainly runs fast compared to what you'd expect. It doesn't run fast compared to a lot of other things, especially if you're taking into account any significant distance.

Comment: @liljoshu: What exactly is your criterion for "wolf-like", though?  Is an Alaskan sled dog "wolf-like"?  How about an Afgan Hound?  As for the speed of a hippopotamus, try outrunning one :-)  (And again, top speed and endurance aren't at all the same thing.)

Comment: @jamesqf top speed and endurance are both factors in outrunning something. As for criterion for "wolf-like" I personally would use "Like a wolf with the exception of stated changes"... in this case, scale. And by that criterion, Alaskan sled dogs would not be wolf-like.

Answer (score 4):

The wolf would lose in a sprint, but could chase it down over a marathon.

Horses have skinny legs and bodies designed for fast bursts. They need a lot of energy to keep going, and they get exhausted quickly.

By contrast, wolves are designed for stamina. They hunt down their prey in packs over long distance. As soon the prey gets tired, the wolves close the distance.

The horsemen would leave the wolf cavalry behind at first. But then the horses tire (especially when carrying a rider) while the wolves keep going for a lot longer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably find that at the same size they're about the same speed.

The smaller animals have more acceleration, the larger ones more endurance. The good old square cube rules come into play again, being taller gives you more stride length, but also more mass, that makes you slower to accelerate.

The bigger problem is feeding them. Larger predators need larger prey, a pack of wolves the size of horses will need to bring down a couple of elephants a week to survive. The largest wolves currently are the Canadian timber wolves and they mostly hunt bison, they need to be larger as a result of the size of their prey but there are still limiting factors.

Comment: This basic analysis seems OK, but you omitted what was discussed [above](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/129450/809) - horses are build to run fast, wolves are built to run long time.

Comment: @Mołot, a lot of that is part of the compensation for scale, the build of wolves and horses is remarkably similar, very skinny lower and fore limbs relative to a heavily muscled rump to drive forwards. Apart from the hooves/paws the builds are remarkably similar.

Comment: "they mostly hunt bison". Well, no. About the only place they CAN hunt bison is in Yellowstone, as most herds are in areas without a wolf population. Even in Yellowstone, wolves prefer elk, and when they do attack bison they generally are attempting to cut out younger animals.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wl8ZxAaB2E

Answer (score 1):

Lets see:
[A horse runs](https://sciencing.com/how-fast-does-horse-run-4683256.html) about 70km/h when super speed and 50km/h when 'normal' gallop
The wolf can run about 50-60 km/h according to google.
A wolf is about 1m high, that means it grow about 50-100% due to this question.
With simple math the wolf could run 75km/h to 120km/h. (unrealistic)
To calculate realistic the legs of the wolf need to get stronger, with that the legs are getting heavier as well as the whole body. The acceleration drops hard and the top speed too. I would estimate the wolf be faster as the horse, but definitely not above 100km/h
I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of horse and the exact details of the wolf. Considering the average horse (according to a lightning search on Google) goes about 48km/h while certain rhino's can reach more than 55km/h I see no reason why a giant wolf couldnt do it.

Comment: Why are you using a rhino as a metric for a wolf? How does the speed of a rhino somehow prove the speed of a wolf of roughly equal scale?

Comment: @Flater a rhino is larger and heavier than a deer and still capable of reaching speeds higher than horses. It also has stubbier legs. These are both counterarguments against the "ah but horses have skinny legs for a reason so a large/deer size wolf wouldnt be able to keep up" reasoning and also show that it all depends on the exact internal build what speeds it could achieve. In this case the OP could just pick a (resonable) speed for the wolves that keeps up/outpaces the horses.

Comment: OP isn't asking if he's able to pick a speed that suits him, but rather if it would be a realistic expectation for wolves to be able to outrun a horse.

Comment: @Flater and the answer is: it depends on how the wolf is build, so he can pick a speed at will within the reasonable bounds of similar size creatures. The Dire Wolf which would have about the right size is theorized to be slower because of its short legs. Since the legs are simply scaled up of this particular wolf it would remain speedy and depend on the exact measurements chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Ligers have a carnivore body plan and at 10 feet long and 750lbs will stand in for your horse sized wolf.  According to this liger enthusiast site, ligers can run 60 mph - twice as fast as a horse.

http://www.ligerworld.com/speed-of-ligers.html

> A liger is capable of gaining a speed momentum of around 50 to 60
>   miles per hour. This 50 to 60 miles per hour speed for a a liger,
>   allows it to be faster than lions and equally faster to the tigers.
>   Furthermore; ligers with this speed are only at the second spot just
>   behind the Cheetahs which are capable of speeding around 70 miles per
>   hour. Dr. Bhagavan Antle is measuring the speed of ligers for many
>   decades at its Animal Preserve (The Institute of Greatly Endangered
>   and Rare Species T.I.G.E.R.S.). He has witnessed the speed of 60 miles
>   per hour from a liger named as Sudan the liger and also an average of
>   50 miles per hour speed from his other ligers as well.

[image: liger]

But somehow I don't see big boy here keeping that kind of speed up for very long.

Answer (score 0):

## Wolves can run down a horse

Wolves [hunt and kill caribou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdVIxS8tgYM) regularly. In that video, a single wolf chases down (and kills a caribou). A caribou's top speed is 60-80 km/h according to [Ultimate Ungulate](http://www.ultimateungulate.com/Artiodactyla/Rangifer_tarandus.html), a source I am partial to. [Guinness](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/fastest-speed-for-a-race-horse/) says the highest speed ever achieved by a racehorse is 70 km/h.

Therefore, if wolves are designed to chase down caribou, and caribou are roughly as fast as horses, it is reasonable for a wolf to chase down a horse.

If the wolf is 4 times larger, then that is even more reason for the wolf to win a footrace.

Comment: speed rarely scales well.

Comment: @John ... but a horse is faster than a rabbit...

Comment: @kingledion: not over the rabbit's preferred racing distance of about 8 feet

Comment: Wolves can run after caribou long enough for it to drop dead from exhaustion, but they cannot run as fast as caribou on short distance.Speed of wolf is only  [50 – 60 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf). Plus, smaller coyotes are faster. Big heavy horses are slower. Fastest dogs are skinny, rather small ones like harts. So scaling wolf up might not allow to even keep its speed.

Comment: @kingledion Horse: 70.76 km/h. Jackrabbit 72 km/h. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastest_animals -- So your comment might be quite opposite to truth, if we are to compare fastest horse to fastest rabbit.

Comment: @Mołot, the jackrabbit isn't a rabbit, it's a hare ;)

Comment: Just because a wolf can outrun a horse (which is correct), doesn't mean that a horse-sized wolf can do the same. You're forgetting the [square cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law#Biomechanics): _If an animal were isometrically scaled up by a considerable amount, its relative muscular strength would be severely reduced, since the cross section of its muscles would increase by the square of the scaling factor while its mass would increase by the cube of the scaling factor. As a result of this, cardiovascular and respiratory functions would be severely burdened._

Comment: Mołot & Separatrix...
The Jackrabbit beats out the horse by a hare.
... I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the wolf's body a bit more then just his size ( with what I mean on his weight ) they could go faster over long distances but not necessarily in a short sprint. 
It's your world so you can give them more stamina ( and lighter body weight, because as I understand no one said that you must make them muscular and ), increase time that they can run before they get hungry and make them more "puffy" then mad stone muscle.  Something like if you tried to make a werewolf.